# When I upload a image It Does not show on database in Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, file-upload

My problem is: When i click to send button with form. All information has been upladed to database exept image. That's why i could not catch to image from database to show users.

[image: Database]

Here is the Migration Codes:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('haberler', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('baslik')->default('');
        $table->string('kategori')->nullable();
        $table->string('icerik')->nullable();
        $table->string('resim')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
        $table->timestamp('updated_at')->useCurrent();
    });
}
```

Here is the function codes

```
public function yenihaberekle(Request $request){
    $request->validate([
        'kategori'=>'required',
        'baslik'=>'required|min:6|max:50',
        'icerik'=>'required|min:50',
        'resim' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);

    $file_name = time() . '.' .request()->resim->getClientOriginalExtension();
    request()->resim->move(public_path('images', $file_name));
    $baslik = $request->baslik;
    $kategori = $request->kategori;
    $icerik = $request->icerik;

    $stu = new haberler();
    $stu->baslik = $baslik;
    $stu->kategori = $kategori;
    $stu->icerik = $icerik;
    $stu->save();
    
    return redirect()->back()->with('success','Haber veya Kampanya Başarıyla Eklenmitir. / News or Campaing has added by succesfuly');
}
```

and i try to catch code on front page

```
  <div class="row">
        @foreach($haberler as $haberler)
            <div class="col-md-4 mb-30">
                <div class="item">
                        <div class="position-re o-hidden"> <img src="{{ asset('images/'. $haberler->resimler) }}" alt="">
                            <div class="date">
                                <a href="post.html"> <span>{{$haberler->created_at->format('M') }}</span> <i>{{$haberler->created_at->format('d') }}</i> </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="con"> <span class="category">
                                <a href="news.html">{{$haberler->kategori}}</a>
                            </span>
                            <h5><a href="post.html">{{$haberler->baslik}}</a></h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach  
        </div>
        <div class="row">
```

and addnews blade i mean form

```
<form method="post" action="{{url('panel/news/addnews/yenihaberekle')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: before the `$stu->save();` you forgot to add the line `$stu->resim = $filename`

Answer (score -1):

Allright guys. I fixed to problem.

First, I forgot in the function:

```
$resim = $file_name;
```

Second, in my view blade my code was:

```html
<img src="{{ asset('images/'. $haberler->resimler) }}"
```

But my function was `resim` so now it works.

thank you

Comment: Your issue is that you are using your language to code instead of english, you must use english, and you have learn more about OOP, as the controller code is not good, you are using `request()` when you have `$request`, the validation should be a `FormRequest` just because it is more organized, etc... simple recommendations, don't take this personal, learn more about PHP and OOP please

Comment: To be honest i dont have any backend experiences it is a big zero. I am watching youtube videos when i turn back to home from my full time job :) it is a different story accualy. So it wast my fault. If there is a fault here, this sould be youtube channel i followed. About your suggestion to languages you are definelty right. Thank you for your advise. Of course i did not offense for your advise. I am not even jounior i am a code monkey. Still i have too much thing to learn

Comment: Oh yeah, no worries at all!!! just check if you can learn about OOP before working with laravel, that will help you a lot!